# Convert datetime to specific format from datatable

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to convert date time value from datatable to only show time value.

I have below code to make this convert process;

```
DateTime ST = DateTime.ParseExact(dtPivot.Rows[e.DataRow][0].ToString(), "HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

ulbTime.Text = ST.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

However this throws an error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I searched however couldn't find a solution for me.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You have a date, convert it to a string, convert it to a date and convert it to a string again. What if you removed the latter two steps?

Comment: What is `dtPivot.Rows[e.DataRow][0].ToString()`?

Comment: if `dtPivot` is a DataTable, you should not have to convert to string then parse - DT columns are types.  The cleverly named `TimeOfDay` property might be what you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks `how to show it` so use String.Format to show the time portion

```
DateTime ST = Convert.ToDateTime(dtPivot.Rows[e.DataRow][0]);

var t = string.Format("{0:hh:mm}",ST);
```

Comment: You could simplify by doing `var example = $"{ST:hh:mm:ss}";`. But +1 for simple approach.

Comment: is $ a c# 6.0 feature?

Comment: True, but we're about to be on C# 8.  So if you're at least on Visual Studio 2013 / 15 you should have access to C# 6.  But yes, a feature of 6 to condense code.

Comment: Yep, it's called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)

Comment: @RufusL Thank you, the name escaped me.

Comment: You might be able to go into your assembly information, change the version of C# to six.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to parse, since the entry being pulled from the database should already be a `DateTime` field.  So in theory, you should be able to pull the data in the following.

```
var model = IDbConnection.Query(query);
var time = model.First().Date.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

So if you're using a object relational mapper, such as Dapper your model has a `DateTime` for the object, then you use the string formatter to do the time.

You could also do:

```
var time = model.First().TimeOfDay();
```

Built directly into the `DateTime` is a time of day, works similar to a date short hand method.  You could obviously use a `DateReader` or `DataTable` accessing the column information index, with a `ToString("hh:mm:ss")` to return the time specifically.   But, you can't do `ToString` in some instances, because a `DBNull.Value` or invalid value will cause a reference exception.  So you'll need to sanitize and ensure those odd values can't be passed.

I prefer the above, because the mapper should associate the value based on your defined type.  So you don't need any extra casting or converting.